# Problem referencing aws_nat_gateway within route table

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

The nat_gateway_id argument in the last resource below is busted. I've been staring at the sun for too long, though, and the issue isn't jumping out at me.

```
resource "aws_eip" "nat_gateway_ip" {
  for_each = aws_subnet.public
  vpc = true
  }
}

# Create NAT gateways in public subnets
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "private" {
  for_each      = aws_subnet.public
  allocation_id = aws_eip.nat_gateway_ip[each.key].id
  subnet_id     = each.value.id
}

# Create Route tables and default routes
resource "aws_route_table" "private" {
  for_each = toset([ "test", "prod"])
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id
  route {
    cidr_block     = "0.0.0.0/0"
    nat_gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.private[each.key].id
  }
}
```

The resulting error is:

```
nat_gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.private[each.key].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ aws_nat_gateway.private is object with 2 attributes
│     │ each.key is "test"
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

Comment: You are using different values in the route table `for_each` compared to what is used in the NAT gateway `for_each`. This means they have different keys and hence cannot be used that way.

Comment: You might also want to look at the VPC module in the terraform registry as it can take care of all of this for you including creating natgateways and route tables.